# How can load the html, get the value and do some calculation by the javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a HTML using javascript to do the following task:

1. loading a HTML such as [here](https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=5&ql=1)
2. put the stock price value in a variable
3. display using that variable for calculation

Comment: Show us what have you done so far

Comment: This is too vague question to answer:
You have a dozen ways to find out this "stock price value".

Answer (score 0):

You can't. XSS protection. Cross site contents can not be read by javascript. No major browser will allow you to do that. Your only option should be making a server-side call then do whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Contact that provider and request/buy access to their information. They might provide you with an endpoint of a Web API (or other service). You can then access it through (for instance) [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://somehosturl/api/stockprices/' // or whatever
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.stockPrices = response;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    HandleError(response);
  });
```

*(based on their general usage sample)*